# Android UI equal spaces between Textviews

Tags: android, xml

I have 3 textviews: textItemRef, textViewName and textViewPrice, I want equal spaces between these 3 textviews but they are overlapping each other. Itried setting weight but it didn't help. where is the problem? Here's my Ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearFirst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/textItemRef1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
      >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textItemRef"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textViewName1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textItemRef1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textViewName1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearFirst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textItemRef1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textItemRef"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textViewName1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPrice"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp" />
```

Comment: wow that worked.. thanks :)

Comment: <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearFirst"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">    I want this to be relative layout.. Linear layout is not working with my functionality.. How to do this without changing parent layouts?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to have nested layout like that instead you can simply have one layout like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView  android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello"/>
<TextView  android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="From"/>
<TextView  android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Jay"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this works :)

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Change : `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` 
with

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

**2)** set the layout_gravity wherever you want.

**3)** Your inside LinearLayout has layout_weight="1" and layout_height="0dp"

**4)** Your TextView has layout_weight=0"

Hope it helps.